# Heroku displays old index.html even after I have deleted it and git commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, web-deployment

After I have re-deployed my app to Heroku, it displays the old public/index.html. What am I missing?

I have done the following steps:

1. $ git rm public/index.html
2. fix the routes.rb to add `root :to => "homes#index"`
3. $ git add .
4. $ git commit -m "changes"
5. $ git clean -f
6. $ git push heroku branch-name:master
7. $ heroku rake:db:migrate
8. $ heroku db:push
9. $ heroku open

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to clean. Just do a simple rm (not git rm) and then git add -A before you commit.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks adymitruk! I guess I will still need a `git clean -f` after merging branches where I deleted files?